# Multiple layer Dropdown menu using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am able to get my dropdown menu to work perfectly, only issue is that i'm having trouble trying to figure out how I can add another dropdown level.

For instance, I want another level to drop down when I hover over Test3.  What am I missing in the code to do so?

CSS:

```
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul id="menu">

<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropbtn">Location</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Test1</a>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
</div>  
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Here are a bunch of examples: http://codepen.io/tag/multilevel/  - but I think multi-level drop-down menus are a terrible user interface. How do they work on small screens? Usually they mean you don't have a solid content strategy.

Comment: @sheriffderek - while I agree that multi-level hover-based dropdowns are pretty passe, the fact that they are handled with CSS means that they are relatively easily converted to other layouts via media queries on smaller screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you didn't close the li tag? Placing a div inside the li seems to make things complicated. 
I think it's easier if you make a new level just wrap everything in a ul-li-ul loop. Like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">SOMETHING LV1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SOMETHING LV1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SOMETHING LV2</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN 2</i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SOMETHING LV3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then hide it and show when hover:

```
#menu li ul{
    display: none;
}
#menu li:hover>ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So you can have two or three levels, no problem.
Please see the fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/fp1x1v05/
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, posted an answer before that didn't isolate the links.

What you want to do, ideally, is target hover events on elements that wrap links, then use a bit more specificity in your selectors.

Try this one:

```
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content ul li {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<nav>
<ul id="menu">

<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropbtn">Location</a>
<ul class="dropdown-content"><li><a href="#">Test1</a><ul><li>Subtest 1</li></ul></li>
<li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test3</a></li></ul>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav ul
        {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        text-align:center;
        }
nav li
        {
        background-color: rgba(0,100,0,0.5);
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        }
nav li:hover
        {
        background-color: rgba(100,0,0,0.5)
        }
nav a
        {
        display:block;
        padding: 0.5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: rgba(0,0,100,0.9);
        }
nav ul ul
        {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        }
nav li:hover > ul
        {
        display: block;
        }
nav ul ul ul
        {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
        }
nav > ul > li > ul > li
        {
        min-width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#"> 1.First </a>
<li>
    <a href="#"> 2.Second </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> 2.1</a>
        <li><a href="#"> 2.2 </a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> 2.2.1 </a>
            <li><a href="#"> 2.2.2 </a>
                <ul>
                <li> <a href="#"> 2.2.2.1 </a>
                <li> <a href="#"> 2.2.2.2 </a>
                </ul>
            </ul>
    </ul>
<li><a href="#"> 3.Third </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```